# Integrating OAuth 2.0 with Google in Next.js and NestJS Applications

Tags: next.js, oauth, nestjs

I am seeking guidance on how to implement  OAuth 2.0 with Google in a web application, using Next.js for the front end and NestJS for the back end. The aim is to establish secure user authentication and consistent login state tracking in the Next.js client while ensuring the NestJS server's API endpoints are securely protected. Essential aspects include methods for token generation, renewal, and verification, along with strategies for secure client-server communication. Additionally, I would appreciate a visual diagram or flowchart that sketches the interactions between the client, server, and OAuth provider within this framework.

Comment: Hey Romel, have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn what are the best questions that fit Stack Overflow. Currently, I'm afraid your question is too broad. We can help you overcome some issues you have with your solution but we will not design one for you.

Comment: Thank you, @MichalTrojanowski, for bringing this to my attention. I am currently investigating this topic and hope to provide a more informed response soon.

Comment: Try to look at [Next-auth](https://next-auth.js.org/) , maybe that can help you